# Open vCard files from browser on Android?

Tags: android, html, web, vcf-vcard, mobile-browser

I would like to skip going to downloads folder to get load a vCard from the browser.

What I have in mind is something like having `<a href="xxx:encoded vCard">Download vCard</a>` that will it pop up the Contacts?

I want android to prompt "complete action with" when for a vCard as is does for the phone numbers.

For example on Xtreamer Aiki `<a href="tel:+1800000000">Call us</a>` will pop up:
`Complete action using`
`Dialer`
`Phone`

Comment: Parse the VCard and append the fields to a view and perform the operation that you want.

Comment: Thank, please excuse my ignorance, I'm newbie to android, can you give me an schematic sample, what do you mean by **VIEW**, and what do I need to do in order to perform the operation (call the `Complete action using` functionality? open Contacts?)

Comment: View us nothing but your Layouts , say after parsing the vCard you get the values . Append the values to the Dialog or Custom view and add the options Complete action using
Dialer . For open contacts you can use intent to start contacts with action save contact
Phone

Comment: thanks @RahulPatil I really appreciate your help. What I need is to indicate the browser to open contacts from the HREF link, but I don't know is how to activate the intent from browser. Can you indicate how to do that or do you know of any tutorial that could help?

Comment: Are you able to parse `vCard` file . Let me know if you can parse the vCard file and get the number then I will tell you how launch contacts or dialer .

Comment: I'm not parsing the `vCard`, I was thinking puting it inside the link of the HREF's link, but I don't know how, encoded? Base64? or some other format. In summary I want to avoid the user to go downloads but just launch the contacts when he get the `vCard`.

Comment: The Contact application will be launched automatically , once you click on the .vcf file .  Are you able to show a pop up with the vCard file ?

Comment: I'm not able to show a pop up with the `vCard` file, how can I do that?